# Regex - Match Digit Until 0 is hit

Tags: regex

I have an integer that is `10001`.

I wish to match the far right digit, up until the first 0, essentially doing a `Right(Str,1)` but because this digit will increase it could end up being a `Right(Str,2)` etc.

Of course if the number is `11111` for example it should match all of it.

Any assistance please, I am using regex101.com to try and figure it out myself but I'm pretty green to regex.

I have

```
[^0]*
```

But this works from left to right, I need it to work right to left.

Comment: MS Office VBA, right? Try just `1+$`. Or split with `0`, and get the last element if it contains `1`.

Comment: any chance you can reverse the digits first ?

Comment: @naomik not ideal, I know this is simple for regex but I dont know how to do a backwards look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
1+$
```

You can use this or

```
[^0]+$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS7gE0/1